# Programmatically change body class

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I need to be able to add a class to the body tag based on the query string.  There is no menu entry where I can set the page class suffix.  Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to have your template listen to the query and take the page class parameter from the url.
Assuming a url of the form:

```
example.com?index.php&pageclass=blablaclass
```

Inside your template `index.php` put the following:

```
<?php
   $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
   $pageclass = $jinput->get('pageclass', 'default_value', 'cmd');
?>

<body class="<?php echo $pageclass; ?>">
```

Answer (score -2):

Ficticious URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com?body_tag_param=blah1;
```

PHP:

```
$param = '';
if(isset($_GET['body_tag_param'])) {
   $param = $_GET['body_tag_param'];
}
switch ($param) {
   case 'blah1' :
      $classname = 'hello1';
   break;
   case 'blah2' :
      $classname = 'hello2';
   break;
   default :
      $classname = 'default_class';
   break;
}
$script = <<<SCRIPT
   <script>
      $(document.body).addClass('{$classname}');
   </script>
SCRIPT;
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag($script);
```

I haven't messed with Joomla or Mootools for a while because they are bulky but that should do it.  Note, the other answer suggests to alter the entry point index.php file, that is a terrible idea.  If you are not sure how the Joomla framework is put together, you might try to add this to your template.. Either way, you should never mess with the index.php file.

Comment: This too is a bad idea. It uses `$_GET` which shouldn't be used in Joomla and requires the jQuery library for such a small feature. As for the other answer, the code can simply be put in the index.php that belongs to the template folder, not the root. If this wasn't a Joomla site, then I would say this would be a good answer, however for Joomla, it's a little overkill :)

Comment: Nope, $_GET is PHP.  Joomla is PHP.  I did not use jQuery, the addClass() is mootools.

Comment: Yes, however Joomla has its own methods and they are getting rid of mootools completely soon

Comment: @Lodder, not sure what the issue is. Right now joomla uses mootools.  I personally hate mootools.  But that is pre-installed.  If you have a  better solution, please provide it (as-is the point of stack-overflow).. Thanks.

Comment: ? Use the APIs.  Just create a JInput instance and get the data from the request.

Comment: @Kevin the other answer is the better solution, no need to post another one. It's simple and works.